# redis-data.rdb will not run/corrupted (maybe)

Tags: redis

i run a discord bot that uses redis, but after i shut down the bot yesterday and restarted it to apply an update, this happened. does anyone know?

```
redis-data     | --- RDB ERROR DETECTED ---
redis-data     | [offset 119004] Invalid LZF compressed string
redis-data     | [additional info] While doing: read-object-value
redis-data     | [additional info] Reading key 'stupidstuff'
redis-data     | [additional info] Reading type 2 (set-hashtable)
redis-data    | [info] 10 keys read
redis-data    | [info] 3 expires
redis-data    | [info] 0 already expired
redis-data exited with code 1
```

here is the entire console log:
     https://pastebin.com/MTPBsKGm

Answer (score 2):

This might be a the dump.rdb is corrupted. Try running the following command to clean up the redis db dump logs:

```
docker volume ls - to find the volume used your redis conrtainer

docker volume rm <name> - to remove the
```